# Loop issue with Google Map markers

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps-api-3

Trying to place markers on a Google Map from a Django backend using the lat and long for each object. Having a very frustrating time doing so. I believe the problem is within the for loop but I can't determine exactly what the issue is (I may just need a second loop). Any aid or insight would be very appreciated.

```
var stories = [{% for story in stories %}
        {latitude:{{story.latitude}},longitude:{{story.longitude}}}, {% endfor %}];




function loadMarkers(stories){
    for (i=0;i<stories.length;i++) {
        var story = stories[i];
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(story.latitude, story.longitude);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: point, map: map});
    }
}

loadMarkers(stories);
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with Django, but if your issues is the pure javaScript code I can offer the first place that I would look.

Check to make sure that you're looping an array and not an object. Every object in javascript has a length property.

Do the below in some debugger like in FF or chrome.

```
function loadMarkers(stories){
for (i=0;i<stories.length;i++) {
    var story = stories[i];
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(story.latitude, story.longitude);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: point, map: map});

console.log(i);
console.log(stories);
console.log(stories[i]);
}
```

}

Comment: Yes, "stories" is an object. So is "story." I need to find a way to iterate through the object.

Comment: Can you give me the info from your log, so I can see what stories and story looks like?

Answer (score 1):

i suggest you check two points:

1)django => there maybe a problem about {{ and }}

2)js = > the last ',' cause an error,you cant make an object like this :{lat:1,lng:2,}

Comment: I did not think you could make an object like that either; however, I just assumed it was some django thing.